# Is there an event to change the value of a control in MS Access before sending it off to validation in the table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a date field with an associated datetime column, and I want to be able to enter relative date string like, say, "m+1" to enter a date exactly one month from today. Is there an event to hook into where I can write **VBA** code that will interpret that and change the field value to an actual date that the validation will understand, before it gets sent off to validation?

I can't seem to find such an event, even `BeforeUpdate` fires too late. I get the `"The value you entered isn't valid for this field."` error message before `BeforeUpdate` fires.

Comment: You have a textbox bound to a Date/Time field? You want this field in a new record to have a default value of Today + 1 month? Use DefaultValue property with a calculation using DateAdd() function. Lock the textbox so users can't edit.

Comment: There is `Change` where you could monitor `myTextbox.Text` for special syntax and edit the text if matched. Would be a weird user experience, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keypress event of the control. And to blow out (to kill the keypress from access control NOT seeing the key, then set keycode = 0.

This routine will thus allow the user to hit
Y or y   = add or subtract a year
D or d   = add or subtract a day
M or m   - add or subtract a month.

Note that you have to use the shift key - caps lock is ignored.

```
Private Sub IvDate_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

  Dim strMyKeys     As String
  strMyKeys = "mdy"       ' key check ignores caps
  If InStr(strMyKeys, Chr(KeyCode)) > 0 Then

     If IsNull(Me.IvDate) Then Me.IvDate = Date

     Select Case KeyCode

        Case Asc("M") And (Shift = 1)

           ' Move ahead one month
           Me.IvDate = DateAdd("m", 1, Me.IvDate)
        Case Asc("M")
           ' move bck one month
           Me.IvDate = DateAdd("m", -1, Me.IvDate)
        Case Asc("D") And (Shift = 1)
           Me.IvDate = DateAdd("d", 1, Me.IvDate)
        Case Asc("D")
           Me.IvDate = DateAdd("d", -1, Me.IvDate)
        Case Asc("Y") And (Shift = 1)
           Me.IvDate = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, Me.IvDate)
        Case Asc("Y")
           Me.IvDate = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Me.IvDate)
     End Select

     KeyCode = 0   ' sends current key to black hole

  End If



End Sub
```